# Cannot authorize request to Google fusion tables API

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I am writing a small java installed application, that will be run on a desktop, to interact with a google fusion table and I keep getting a 401 unauthorized error. Here is the code I am using to connect to and query the table:

```
/** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
/** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

private static void insertData(String query) throws IOException {
    BasicAuthentication credential = new BasicAuthentication(username, password);
    fusiontables = new Fusiontables.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
            "Google-FusionTablesSample/1.0").build();
    Query q = fusiontables.query();
    Sql sql = q.sql(query);

    try {
        sql.execute();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

    }
}
```

The table was created in my account and I am using my account's username and password, so I know it's not that I am using the wrong login info. This is my first time doing anything with java and oauth so can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be doing basic authentication (which is sending your username and password in clear with each request), that is not OAuth at all. I don't think the fusion table API supports basic auth.

This is the OAuth 2 documentation:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Be very careful with your password, do not send it in API calls.